# Weird difference between pages in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm getting a weird difference in a container for two buttons in width and "padding" between two pages in Firefox.  I've dug through the HTML and the CSS but can find no reason for this difference.  The only difference between the pages is the interior page has a div that renders the main content block (called #rt-main) but that is outside of the area that has the problem.

Take a look at: [Problem page](http://www.intentionalbranding.com/10-portfolio/2-port-maria-schonder#showcase)

Right above this you'll see two buttons (See our Menu of Services and View Some of Our Work) - in FF these differ from:

[Good page](http://www.intentionalbranding.com/#showcase) yet the HTML and CSS are the same for those.  Is this a bug in Firefox? Or am I missing something?

```
<div class="design-menu"><a href="#list" class="large-button ">See our Menu of Services</a> <a href="#showcase" class="large-button ">View Some of our Work</a></div>
```

Just be aware the problem exists when you view the site at 1200px+ wide resolution.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? Links to the real site will break, so the question wouldn't be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Huh...pretty cool tool.  Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: The two fiddles look identical to me....

Comment: Are you able to view them in full resolution?  The problems only show at full size.

Comment: They look identical to me as well, at 1920 x 1200, in FF 27.0.1

Comment: Apparently the JS fiddle won't show it then.  Remember the problem only exists in Firefox at full resolution.  Updated the links to the live URLs.